# How to have multiple sheets in Excel ActiveReports 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, activereports

I can generate one sheet, but I can't find a way to generate multiple sheets in one Excel file.

I tried to use `GrapeCity.SpreadBuilder.Workbook` but I haven't found a way to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using [ActiveReports](http://activereports.grapecity.com) The excel export in ActiveReports is used to export the report as it appears.   in the latest version of ActiveReports we have an Excel transformation device that allows you to break the report over multiple excel sheets.

the following sample of code creates workbook with 2 sheets via SpeadBuilder API:

```
        GrapeCity.SpreadBuilder.Workbook sb = new GrapeCity.SpreadBuilder.Workbook();

        sb.Sheets.AddNew();
        sb.Sheets[0].Cell(1, 1).SetValue("Sheet #1");

        sb.Sheets.AddNew();
        sb.Sheets[1].Cell(1, 1).SetValue("Sheet #2");
```